# Is the hemisphere of $S^4$ the unique compact 4-dimensional manifold with $\partial K = S^3$?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, compact-manifolds, manifolds-with-boundary, orbifolds

The first question is

> Is the hemisphere of $S^4$ the unique compact 4-dimensional manifold with $\partial K = S^3$?

In other words, is it obvious?

The question stems from a theoretical physics paper by Micha Berkooz (on the arXiv) on the supergravity dual of a (1,0) field theory in six dimensions. The paper is [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9802195). However, my questions really have to do with mathematics.

The second related question is on orbifolds. Specifically,

> What is the general relation of $S^{n}/\mathbb{Z}_2$ to some segement (hemisphere?) of $S^{n}$?

For instance, $S^{1}/\mathbb{Z}_2$ is a line interval (simply half the circumference of the circle) with two fixed points. The paper referred to above seems to orbifold $S^{4}$ and replace it by a hemisphere of $S^{4}$.

Suppose I parametrize $S^{n}$ by $n$-dimensional spherical coordinates $(r, \phi_1, \phi_2, \ldots, \phi_{n-2}, \phi_{n-1})$ where $r = \text{constant}$, and $\phi_{i} \in [0, \pi]$ for $1 \leq i \leq n-2$ while $\phi_{n-1} \in [0, 2\pi)$.

Is it correct to think of $S^{n}/\mathbb{Z}_2$ as the $\mathbb{Z}_2$ modding out a particular $\phi$ (which parametrizes the great arc of $S^4$, and ranges from $0$ to $\pi$) to give a hemisphere (by restricting its range to $[0, \pi/2]$)?

EDIT: I changed the $\phi_{n-1}$ in the second question to "a particular $\phi$..."

EDIT #2: A closely related construction of this kind of orbifold is described here: https://books.google.com/books?id=OG0GBwAAQBAJ&lpg=PP1&pg=PA275#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: No, of course not, e.g. you can take connect sum with $\mathbb{CP}^2$. What you mean by $S^n/\mathbb{Z}_2$ depends on what action of $\mathbb{Z}_2$ you have in mind; do you mean a reflection?

Comment: By $\mathbb{Z}_2$ on a particular coordinate $x$, I mean the identification of $x$ with $-x$. In the physics setting, there's a theory on $AdS_7 \times K$ where $K$ is a compact manifold that realizes an $SO(4)$ global symmetry. The $SO(4)$ symmetry (and the knowledge that $S^3 = SO(4)/SO(3)$) tell me that there's a 3-sphere involved somehow. It turns out that $K$ is a 4-dimensional manifold. The paper says "K is made of a bundle of a 3-sphere over a 1-dimensional manifold." 

(K is 4D as it is described by $U=f(x^6,..,x^9, x^10) = \text{const.}$)

Comment: I slightly edited my question. Perhaps it makes more sense now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the sake of having an answer: no, the disk $D^4$ (mathematicians' notation for the hemisphere in $S^4$) is not the unique compact $4$-manifold with boundary $S^3$. Starting from any closed $4$-manifold $M$, you can cut a hole out of it to get a compact $4$-manifold with boundary $S^3$, and most of these are different (they can be distinguished e.g. by their homology); in the comments I effectively suggested that you do this with $M = \mathbb{CP}^2$.

More generally, given any manifold $M$ with boundary $\partial M$, you can take the [connected sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_sum) with a closed manifold of the same dimension, and the result is another manifold (usually different, and again you can usually tell the difference using e.g. homology) with the same boundary.

With $\mathbb{Z}_2$ acting by reflection, the quotient $S^n/\mathbb{Z}_2$ can be identified as a set with the disk $D^n$, and as an orbifold every point on the boundary $S^{n-1}$ has stabilizer $\mathbb{Z}_2$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Qiaochu Yuan! The physics description of the orbifold is at https://books.google.com/books?id=OG0GBwAAQBAJ&lpg=PP1&pg=PA275#v=onepage&q&f=false, if you're interested.